# What is the best practice to avoid utterance conflicts in an Alexa Skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

In the screenshot below, I have got an utterance conflict, which is obvious because I am using similar patterns of samples in both the utterances.

[image]

My question is, the skill I am developing requires similar kind of patterns in multiple utterances and I cannot force users to say something like “Yes I want to continue”, or “I want to store…”, something like this.

In such a scenario what is the best practice to avoid utterance conflicts and that too having the multiple similar patterns?

I can use a single utterance and based on what a user says, I can decide what to do.

Here is an example of what I have in my mind:

User says something against `{note}`
In the skill I check this:

```
if(this$inputs.note.value === "no") {
  // auto route to stop intent
} else if(this$inputs.note.value === "yes") {
  // stays inside the same intent
} else {
  // does the database stuff and saves the value.
  // then asks the user whether he wants to continue
}
```

The above loop continues until the user says “no”.

But is this the right way to do it? If not, what is the best practice?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is really that for those two intents you have slots with no context around them. I'm also assuming you're using these slots as catch-all slots meaning you want to capture everything the person says.

From experience: this is very difficult/annoying to implement and will not result in a good user experience.

For the `HaveMoreNotesIntent` what you want to do is have a separate `YesIntent` and `NoIntent` and then route the user to the correct function/intent based on the intent history (aka [context](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/data/user#context)). You'll have to just enable this in your config file.

```
YesIntent() {
  console.log(this.$user.$context.prev[0].request.intent);
  // Check if last intent was either of the following
  if (
    ['TutorialState.TutorialStartIntent', 'TutorialLearnIntent'].includes(
      this.$user.$context.prev[0].request.intent
    )
  ) {
    return this.toStateIntent('TutorialState', 'TutorialTrainIntent');
  } else {
    return this.toStateIntent('TutorialState', 'TutorialLearnIntent');
  }
}
```

OR if you are inside a [state](https://www.jovo.tech/docs/routing#states) you can have yes and no intents inside that state that will only work in that state.

```
ISPBuyState: {
  async _buySpecificPack() {
    console.log('_buySpecificPack');
    this.$speech.addText(
      'Right now I have a "sports expansion pack". Would you like to hear more about it?'
    );
    return this.ask(this.$speech);
  },
  async YesIntent() {
    console.log('ISPBuyState.YesIntent');
    this.$session.$data.productReferenceName = 'sports';
    return this.toStatelessIntent('buy_intent');
  },
  async NoIntent() {
    console.log('ISPBuyState.NoIntent');
    return this.toStatelessIntent('LAUNCH');
  },
  async CancelIntent() {
    console.log('ISPBuyState.CancelIntent()');
    return this.toStatelessIntent('LAUNCH');
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will try the way

Comment: Can you please explain the `['TutorialState.TutorialStartIntent', 'TutorialLearnIntent'].includes( this.$user.$context.prev[0].request.intent)`. Also please tell me the differences between `this.ask(..)` and `return this.ask(...)`. Thank you!

Comment: Sure! To answer your first question, I'm saying if `this.$user.$context.prev[0].request.intent` (the previous intent) is in this list of intents `['TutorialState.TutorialStartIntent', 'TutorialLearnIntent']` do x.

Comment: To your second question, some of my intents are [asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) so I'm adding to the this.$speech variable and then saying that to the user asynchronously.